# Best way of linking to a page in Django

Tags: python, django

I managed to create a URL tag for my index. But right now I'm confused how to add links to other pages.

I put this on my **urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
```

The next thing I put this tag into the href:

```
{% url 'index' %}
```

But what if I wanted to create a new page and would be linking to it. How would I do it the best way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So next you would extend your `urls.py` to look something like this:

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
url(r'^blog$', 'blog', name='blog'),
```

Then in your html you can use either one:

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
```

You can of course use the template tage `{% url 'index' %}` as many times as you need in any template.

Answer (score 33):

Django has updated urlpatterns to take 'path' instead of using url so it's become much more efficient. You don't have to use regex anymore

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index , name='index'),
    path('blog/', views.blog , name='blog'),]
```

Then in templates, you can use template tagging

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Index</a>
<a href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a>
```

If you have multiple apps, you can tag it as follows. For example, if this is under 'post' app:

In post app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'post'
urlpatterns=[
    path('', views.index , name='index'),
    path('blog/', views.blog , name='blog'),]
```

in the project urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns=[
path('post/', include('post.urls'),]
```

In templates, you do as following:

```
<a href="{% url 'post:index' %}">Index</a>
<a href="{% url 'post:blog' %}">Blog</a>
```

Comment: So we can directly use page name

Comment: Might be useful to try to be as clear as possible in your post... I have an applet called `my_applet`. I want it to try and allow a link from one page in `my_applet` to another page in `my_applet`... once all the url patterns are declared inside of `my_applet`'s urls.py and then I add them to django's main urls.py (for the project) then, to go from one url inside of `my_applet` to another, all I have to do is say `<a href="{% url 'url_inside_of_my_applets_urls.py_file/' %}"...</a>` The above should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the same label `{% url 'index' %}`.
You may use each `name` in urls.py to link to the url.

urls.py

```
url(r'^archive/$', 'mysite.views.archive',name='archive'),
url(r'^about/$', 'mysite.views.about',name='about'),
url(r'^contact/$', 'mysite.views.contact',name='contact'),
```

template

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
<a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
```

If you have many apps, use `namespace`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs

Answer (score 2):

Use the below syntax:

```
<a href="{% url 'cart' %}" > Cart page </a>
```

Where URL 'cart' is the name field in your app URL pattern.

```
urlpatterns = [
    #Leave as empty string for base url
    path('', views.shop, name="store"),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),--------------------->
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),
    path('shop/',views.shop, name="shop"),

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new URL in the same format and give that name instead of index.

Eg:

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
url(r'^new/page/$', 'new', name='new_page'),

{% url 'new_page' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                       url(r'^about/$', views.about', name='about'),
)
```

Now, in the html template rendered by your `views.index` you can have:

```
<a href ="{% url 'about' %}">about</a>
```