# How to create a link between two html files in local server using django

Tags: html, django, web, hyperlink, local

I have a project "something". In something/shop/templates/shop I have HTML [files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUwUg.png).

I want to have a link between **'main'** and **'about'** html files, but I do not know how. I tried to do it as in usual HTML file, but it is not working.

```
<a href="about.html"> About </a>
```

Also I tried this way, but it is not working too.

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}"> About </a>
```

It is in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
               path('', views.main, name='main'),
               path('about/', views.about, name='about'),]
```

views.py:

```
def main(request):
    return render(request, 'shop/main.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'shop/about.html')
```

What should I write to get a normal link between them?

Comment: But your about page doesn't even work at all, as it has the same URL as the home page. You need to have different URLs for each view.

Comment: A similar question has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938101/best-way-of-linking-to-a-page-in-django